# merge 2 dataframes in r with same row names

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, merge, row-number

I have 2 dataframes and I want to merge them into one dataframe each corresponding to eachother's row name values. If you could show me how to map them on a plot (ggplot2 or plot), that would be much appreciated.

---

df1:

```
structure(list(`12m yield` = c("4.72", "7.07", "3.08")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("HUKX", 
"HRUB", "EUN"))
```

df2:

```
structure(list(Volatility101 = c(25.25353177644, 42.1628734949414, 
28.527736824123)), row.names = c("EUN", "HRUB", "HUKX"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `merge`, we can use the `by` as `row.names`

```
out <- merge(df1, df2, by = 'row.names')
```

---

If we need to plot, either we can use `base R` `barplot`

```
barplot(`row.names<-`(as.matrix(out[-1]),
          out$Row.names), col = c('blue', 'green', 'red'), legend = TRUE)
```

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
merge(df1, df2, by = 'row.names') %>% 
   rename(nm = 'Row.names') %>%  # // rename the column name
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%  # // some columns were not of the correct type
   pivot_longer(cols = -nm) %>% # // reshape to 'long' format
   ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = nm)) + # // plot as bar
        geom_col() + 
        theme_bw()
```

-output

[image]

Comment: I was thinking more scatter-plot, but thanks for the merge part.